# Communicating to Applications on LAN

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, networking, network-programming

I want to code an app with recreational purposes. This should be a Desktop app that detects itself running on other computers on the same LAN and communicates with them. By communication I mean that I should be able to pass anything from on to another.

Please note that although I'm not asking for code (that would beat my purpose, of course) I think some small snippets wouldn't hurt. In any case what I really want is the "recommended procedure", I mean what Microsoft recommends for this environment, and documentation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is your first ever network application, you should start with sockets so you can understand and appreciate the issues involved in building an app like this from scratch. Effectively, what you are trying to build is a peer-to-peer application. There are many things you'll want to think about and research here, like:

1. Peer discovery -- detecting other instances on the network and figuring out if they're still online or not
2. Messaging -- designing an on the wire protocol for your app
3. Security -- things like encryption, preventing replay
   attacks, etc.

Eventually (once you've understood the underlying concepts), you will want to defer all of this to a framework rather than developing everything from scratch. I think [WCF peer-to-peer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297274.aspx) will fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

As Taz said socket programming is the best choice but you can use other solutions like `WCF` (not recommended normally).

About finding other instances on the `LAN` I could say you need some scanning algorithm. Most `worms` have such an algorithm for spreading. You should consider many networking issues like open ports on target `LAN` and firewall restrictions.

Another point could using a `TCP` port over 5000 (up to 65535, but don't use famous ports) since ports under 5000 are subject to be used by operating system.

Also to need your own protocol over TCP/IP for messaging/commanding and data transfer between peers.

At the end it's a good idea to have a hand from a networking/security consultant in this kind of projects since most problems you encounter are not about programming but networking.

Comment: I'm only coding this application to precisely learn all those issues you mention... I have no intention to build an application to deploy whatsoever. I'm just looking to widen my knowledge on network communications, subject of which I know basically nothing...

Comment: Good. So don't worry about networking issues. First, you need a test environment. Simply use multiple virtual machines(Microsoft virtual machine is good choice) and start by writing to console applications communicating over `TCP/IP` and writing results on console, one as server and another as client. Then you can write more complex ones (both server/client peers)

Answer (score 1):

Socket programming? Make them listen on a specific port and whenever application starts it should connect to that socket and the they are both connected. I am not sure how should application search for other application instances running on LAN.

Comment: That is the idea :) but how can I listen to ports and connect to them?